# Wrap every 2nd image in a div if it's portrait

Tags: jquery

I have a list of images and I want to wrap every 2 images in a div. However if the image is landscape I want to wrap it in it's own div.

Here is my code so far, it's working for the portraits but it's wrapping the landscapes too.

```
$("#dps-inner").find('img').each(function (i) {
    jQuery(this).height(600);
    jQuery(this).width('auto');

    $(this).load(function () {
        var width = jQuery(this).width();
        //console.log(width);
        var height = jQuery(this).height();

        if (width > 600) {
            jQuery(this).addClass("landscape");
        }
        else {
            jQuery(this).addClass("portrait");
        }

        accum_width += width + 1
        $("#dps-inner").width(w * i);
    });
});

var images = $("#dps-outer").find("#dps-inner > img");

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i += 2) {
    images.slice(i, i + 2).wrapAll("<div class='images'></div>");
}
```

I have also tried

```
var images = $("#dps-outer").find("#dps-inner > img.portrait");

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i += 2) {
    images.slice(i, i + 2).wrapAll("<div class='images'></div>");
}
```

and even

```
var images = $("#dps-outer").find("#dps-inner > img");

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i += 2) {
    if (images.width() < 600) {
        images.slice(i, i + 2).wrapAll("<div class='images'></div>");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I have tried to unwrap the landscape image once everything has been completed but that doesn't work either, it's like there's no callback and everything is being done at the exact same time.

Has anyone any suggestions?

My fiddle isn't going to work as the screen needs to be wider but maybe you can open it in another window, it's just to get an idea of what I'm trying to do

http://jsfiddle.net/tara_irvine/r46XA/

Comment: If you add `show` after your fiddle url it will open full screen - http://jsfiddle.net/tara_irvine/r46XA/1/show/

Comment: So what happens with the odd numbered `portrait` image that is next to a landscape? Should it be in its own wrapper? Or should it relocate the next `portrait` to be alongside it?

Comment: Essentially there won't be any, I have a say in the ordering of the images and I'll always put 2 portraits together. I think that would make it harder. Thanks for the question. @RightSaidFred

Comment: Ok so I've been fiddling and I think http://jsfiddle.net/tara_irvine/r46XA/10/ this explains what I need a little better sorry for the confusion. So far it's working but every 2 images is wrapped, I only want to wrap the portrait ones. Is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, do this:

```
var outer = $("#dps-outer");

  // wrap adjacent .portrait elements
outer.find("#dps-inner > img.portrait + img.portrait").each(function() {
    var prev = $(this).prev('img.portrait');
    if( prev.length ) {
        prev.add( this ).wrapAll("<div class='images'></div>");
    }
});

  // wrap .landscape elements
outer.find("#dps-inner > img.landscape").wrap("<div class='images'></div>");

  // wrap any lingering .portrait elements 
  //   (usually an odd one between a pair of portraits, and a landscape)
outer.find("#dps-inner > :not(img.portrait) + img.portrait").wrap("<div class='images'></div>");
```

<s>Only thing this doesn't do is deal with odd numbered `portrait` images. You'll need to describe what to do with those.</s>

I'll just assume you wanted the odd `.portrait` to be wrapped on its own, and not relocated.

---

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8quyZ/)** *The demo is altered to make it easier to visualize the result.*

---

Or like this to eliminate a DOM selection:

```
var outer = $("#dps-outer");

outer.find("#dps-inner > img.portrait + img.portrait")
    .each(function() {
        var prev = $(this).prev('img.portrait');
        if (prev.length) {
            prev.add(this).wrapAll("<div class='images'></div>");
        } else if( !$(this).next('img.portrait').length ) {
            $(this).wrap("<div class='images'></div>");
        }
    });

outer.find("#dps-inner > img.landscape").wrap("<div class='images'></div>");
```

---

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8quyZ/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer that looks great, I tried it but it's not working, the class portrait or landscape is only being added to the images once they are loaded and their heights and widths have been checked. I think this is where the problem lies.

Comment: @TaraIrvine: Yeah sorry, I meant for this to be used after the classes have been applied. So you'd need to run it directly after your code that applies those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the height is bigger then the width, thus portait. If the width is bigger then the height => landscape? so you should just change the 600 to height like so:

```
 if (width > height) {
     jQuery(this).addClass("landscape");
 } else {
    jQuery(this).addClass("portrait");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.isPortrait = function(){
    var elem = this[0];
    if (elem && elem.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
        return elem.width < elem.height;
    }
    return;
};
$.fn.isLandscape = function(){
    var elem = this[0];
    if (elem && elem.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
        return elem.width < elem.height;
    }
    return;
};

$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    portrait: function(el){
        if (el && el.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'IMG'){
            return el.height > el.width;
        }
        return false;
    },
    landscape: function(el){
        if (el && el.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'IMG'){
            return el.width > el.height;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

There's some added image flexibility. You can now grab:

```
// NOTE: For any of these to work, the image would needs to be already loaded,
// or the height/width attributes would need to be supplied. Otherwise, this will
// be making decisions on the absence of information.

// returns status on FIRST image element found in collection
$('img').isPortrait();  // returns if the image is portrait
$('img').isLandscape(); // returns if the image is landscape

// Filters all images found
$('img:portrait');      // filters for only portrait images
$('img:landscape');     // filters for only landscape images
```

From there, going back to your original question:

```
$('img:landscape').wrap('<div/>',{class:'landscapeOnly'});
$('#dps-inner img:portrait:nth-child(2n-1)').each(function(a){
  $(this).add($(this).next('p')).wrapAll('<div/>');
});
```